# Having Issues Passing a value from one Fragment to another

Tags: android-fragments

Hi I'm a real beginner to mobile programming with Java so bear with me.
I'm trying to pass a value from one Fragment to another using a Bundle but the result I'm getting is a null value in the destination Fragment.

> Source Fragment

```
public static CourseFragment newInstance(String idNO) {
    CourseFragment courseFragment = new CourseFragment();
    Bundle sendID = new Bundle();

    idNO = sendIDNO;

    sendID.putString("ID", idNO);
    courseFragment.setArguments(sendID);
    return courseFragment;
}
```

}

> Destination Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container, false);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        sentID = this.getArguments().getString("ID");

    }
```

I'm pretty sure I've made a lot of mistakes here and the code's pretty fugly but I'm taking one day at a time.

Comment: Hi there mate. Could you edit your question and specify where in your code you're creating and passing the data to the other fragment please?

Comment: Ah sorry...first time using stack T_T

Comment: It's ok! :) In your code, are you using 'childFragmentManager'? Because you need to use that to create a fragment within a fragment

Comment: Ah I haven't used that. Frankly I don't even know what that is xD.In my project I have a main activity with its layout and 3 fragments each with their respective layouts and use it to make a tabbed layout. Do I need that to pass data between the 3 layouts?

Comment: Also I'm using a Viewpager to setup the tabs

Comment: these 2 fragments you talk about, are two fragments inside the viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay mate. If you want to start a fragment from within a fragment you've got to do this:

```
MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment.newInstance(myValue);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And your class `MyFragment` should receive a parameter in the method `newInstance()`

*inside MyFragment class*

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String string) {
    MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("string", string);
    newFragment.setArguments(args);

    return newFragment;
```

This will replace your current fragment with the new fragment.

Comment: I have a lot going on too man xD I understand. I've been super swamped with school work so i haven't gotten around to answering.

'MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment.newInstance(myValue);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();'

I actually removed this part since I didn't know what it did. I was scouring the internet for a solution.

Comment: The whole project started with a new Tabbed Activity in Android Studio and I then created 3 fragments that would be displayed and the user can swipe between the three tabs but I was having trouble sending information between them e.g. a previously entered ID number.